# How to return a promise as well as close the mysql connection in the same code in NodeJS

Tags: mysql, node.js, promise, database-connection

We want our function to return a promise as well as close the database connection. We put the promise in try and connection closing command in finally to which it gives the following errors -

```
conPool.close()  //It says  Error - conPool.close() is not a function

conPool.release() // Error - conPool.release() is not a function

conPool.releaseConnection(); // Error - Cannot read property '_pool' 
                                          of undefined
```

Please help me close the mySQL connection. I want to return my data . But after return nothing works so the connection doesn't close. I am afraid i may loose out on maximum limit. I have even set maximum connections in mySQL but still. And there is a possible solution that i may declare conPool outside the function and make all the functions use this single conPool but this is also not working.

code -

```
function viewChoice() {


    var sqlQuery;

        sqlQuery = "select * from TRANSACTION_PAYLOAD where INTERFACE_NAME 
     = 'Vehicle RC' AND (STATUS ='INPUT_ERROR' OR STATUS ='ERROR')";



    }


    var deferred = Q.defer();



    var host = config.host;
    var user = config.user;
    var password = config.password;
    var database = config.database;



    var conPool = mysql.createPool({
        host: host,
        user: user,
        password: password,
        database: database
    });


try{
    conPool.getConnection(function (err) {
        console.log("Inside getConnection ")
        if (err)
            deferred.reject(err.name + ': ' + err.message);

        conPool.query(sqlQuery,
            function (err, result, fields) {
                if (err) deferred.reject(err.name + ': ' + err.message);


                console.log(result);
                deferred.resolve(result);
            });
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}

finally{
    console.log("inside  Finally")
    conPool.releaseConnection();

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

From MySQL connector [docs](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#closing-all-the-connections-in-a-pool) :

> Closing all the connections in a pool
>   When you are done using the pool, you have to end all the connections or the Node.js event loop will stay active until the connections are closed by the MySQL server. This is typically done if the pool is used in a script or when trying to gracefully shutdown a server. To end all the connections in the pool, use the end method on the pool:

`pool.end(function (err) {
  // all connections in the pool have ended
});`

> The end method takes an optional callback that you can use to know when all the connections are ended.
>
> Once pool.end is called, pool.getConnection and other operations can no longer be performed. Wait until all connections in the pool are released before calling pool.end. If you use the shortcut method pool.query, in place of pool.getConnection → connection.query → connection.release, wait until it completes.
>
> pool.end calls connection.end on every active connection in the pool. This queues a QUIT packet on the connection and sets a flag to prevent pool.getConnection from creating new connections. All commands / queries already in progress will complete, but new commands won't execute.

Plus you may move your `return deferred.promise;`  inside `finally` block